# Draw on background of Gnome Shell panel

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I want to visualize some data on the background of the Gnome Shell top panel, behind all of the other elements. Like in this mockup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv1aH.jpg

Playing around with other extensions and reading through the St API docs [2] I found no obvious way to do something like this. The only elements in Main.panel that have insert functions (e.g.  _insert_child_at_index) are _leftBox and _rightBox, but that's not what I want since I want my visualization to be *behind* the other elements, not next to them.

Ideally, I'd like to dynamically add/remove and absolutely position elements anywhere inside Main.panel (or behind it if that's possible), without affecting any of the existing elements.

Comment: I have no experience with it myself, but I know GIMP and a few other graphics editing tools to support being called from a CLI/headless env. You could try to generate an image that way and set it as the background for `Main.panel` and/or its child elements. Also keep in mind to set the background of any elements that cover it to `background-color: transparent !important;` to make sure the image is visible